# I have a nodejs repo on local. How do i push it to github?

Tags: node.js, git, github, repository

I have a nodejs repo on my local dev. How do i push the repo to github repo?

Also i would like to automate build to every github push to this repo with codeBuild or circle ci. Does anyone have any feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

As for pushing (on premise?) repo to GitHub: [add a new remote and push to it](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/).

As for building upon GitHub push: [you can add a hook that will trigger an action every time new commit is pushed](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/).

Comment: I don't have a repository yet. Would like to understand the suggested flow to create one and push your local project to that repository.

Comment: @user461112 I would create a new GitHub repository, checkout it, copy over the existing code and commit it as a whole.